# Create function in Parse Cloud Code that does not require authorisation

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, slack-api

I have my own instance of [Parse Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) running on AWS and until now Cloud Functions have been working great, but with one caveat: they cannot be successfully called publicly, i.e. they require an authorisation key be sent in the REST request header.

I want to set up a [Slack Slash Command](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) to my server, and it has to be able to POST a payload without any headers or extra parameters. As a result, my requests are currently unauthorised (returning 403 statuses).

Is there a way to create granular control over a Parse Cloud Function's authorisation (i.e. if it requires master-key header or not), and if not — is there a way of forwarding the request but still through the Parse server?—Or even a way of manipulating the headers of a Slack request? I would rather not have to use another service just for request forwarding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two options

Pass in the master key on the client request which should bypass authorization. It's a blunt approach but might be okay in your case (without knowing more details).

Or run a new express endpoint alongside parse and from there call the parse cloud function using the masker key.

```
var api = new ParseServer(...)
var app = express();
app.use('/parse', api);
app.get('/api/slack', function(req, res) {
    //call cloud function passing in master key
    // add X-Parse-Master-Key as http header
    unirest.post("http://myhost.com:1337/parse/functions/mycloudfunction")
    .headers({'X-Parse-Master-Key', MASTER_KEY)
    .end(function(response) {
     }
```